# html dom editing/adding attributes/functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have got something like this in html

```
<div class="change"><div>
<div class="change"><div>
<div class="change"><div>
<div class="change"><div>
```

Now here we go for the java script

```
var base = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
base[0].setAttribute();
console.log(base[0]);
```

From the console I can see that I"m getting an object but I can't edit it this way, is there any other possibility to edit/add attributes( i need to add a onclick function to like 100 elements).
It's pretty difficult to get the higer object by document.getElementById,
so... anyone got a solution for this?^^

Comment: `b` is actually `base`, right?

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: For adding handlers to your 100 elements, you could just use a loop.

Comment: I find this to be a perfect use case for JQuery. Using selectors instead of manually writing loops is a lot less error prone.

Comment: @TGH - It's not hard to write a loop: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function (el) { el.addEventListener(fn); });` (or a traditional `for(;;)` would work as well... I think a "perfect" use-case for jQuery is having to support older versions of IE, not to avoid loops.

Comment: @tjameson Jquery is first and foremost a productivity framework. It gives the developer easy and consistent ways to do DOM manipulation. Doing it manually is always an option too, but I find that these things can more easily be solved using JQuery. However, why not offer your solution as an answer? That way the OP can decide and reward the answer he/she likes best.

Comment: @TGH - There's already 6 answers, two of which don't use jQuery, so I think that's probably sufficient, especially since the OP hasn't even returned for comment.

Comment: Yes b is base sry :P edited it already ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add attributes like this

```
var element = document.getElementByClassName('change')[0];
element.setAttribute(attributeName,attributeValue);
```

Comment: Well i was trying this many times yet today i tried it once again and it worked -_- guess i was damn tired at that 3am ; D Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Then it's just a matter of doing something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.change').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('class', 'new-value');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UuFJs/).

Comment: He is using plain javascript. jQuery shouldn't be the answer to everything. And why should he use a 40K+ library for this simple step?

Comment: Where is the requirement for "plain javascript"?

Comment: It was not originally tagged with jQuery but, no matter, my original response still stands.

Comment: @Rob I disagree with you (and so do most people considering the popularity of jQuery). At the of the day, jQuery is *probably* the better solution. People use it because it makes client-side JavaScript cleaner. It's silly to assume this is the only requirement in his entire application. As the app grows in complexity, jQuery will be more and more useful. I recommend the original poster start off on the right foot.

Comment: @TGH It's not up to your personal preference or mine.

Comment: @senfo It's no sillier than your assumption he will need or want to use jQuery.

Comment: @Rob, I'm done discussing this with you after this. The original question is tagged with jQuery (at time of this comment, I see no edits). If you have any better ideas, let's see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the code below:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.change'),
    length = nodes.length,
    counter = 0;

for (; counter < length; counter += 1) {
    // set an attribute.
    nodes[counter].setAttribute('data-test', 'test' + counter);
    // add a click event.
    nodes[counter].addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert('Yep, you clicked me');
    }, false);
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stavarotti/zx2vY/)

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery:

```
 $('.change').on('click', function() {
    // Action
});
```

Syntax of setAttributte:

```
Object.setAttributte(attribute, value);
```